# Call a method after Spring Boot app starts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have a Java Spring Boot application which has a Scheduler which calls a async task from a Service The task takes a few minutes (usually 3-5mins) to complete.

The same async method from the Service can also be called trough a UI Application, by calling the API from the Spring Boot Controller.

Code:

**Scheduler**

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */1 * * ?")
  public void scheduleAsyncTask() {
    myService.doAsync();
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  @Async("threadTaskExecutor")
  public void doAsync() {
    //Do Stuff
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mysrv")
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @CrossOrigin
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void postAsyncUpdate() {
    myService.doAsync();
  }
}
```

The scheduler runs the async task every hour, but a user can also run it manually from the UI.

But, I do not want the async method to run again if it is already in the middle of execution.

In order to do that, I have created a table in DB which contains a flag which goes on when the method is running and then it is turned off after the method completes.

Something like this in my service class:

```
@Autowired
private MyDbRepo myDbRepo;

@Async("threadTaskExecutor")
public void doAsync() {
  if (!myDbRepo.isRunning()) {
    myDbRepo.setIsRunning(true);
    //Do Stuff
    myDbRepo.setIsRunning(false);
  } else {
    LOG.info("The Async task is already running");
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is that the flag sometimes gets stuck due to various reasons (app restarting, some other application error etc.)

So, I want to reset the flag in DB each time the spring boot application is deployed and whenever is restarts.

How can I do that? Is there some way to run a method just after the Spring Boot Application starts, from where I can call a method from my Repo to un set the flags in the database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check for the @PostConstruct for e.g here https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Comment: Thanks!  this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do some stuff after whole application booted and ready use below sample [from](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/13/run-code-at-spring-boot-startup/)

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationStartup 
implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  /**
   * This event is executed as late as conceivably possible to indicate that 
   * the application is ready to service requests.
   */
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    // here your code ...

    return;
  }

} // class
```

If it is enough to hook after a single bean creating use `@PostConstruct` as suggested by @loan M

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case , you need to reset the database after application deployment, so the best way for you to do that is to use the **Spring CommandLineRunner** .

> Spring boot provides a CommanLineRunner interface with a callback run() method which can be invoked at application startup
>   after the Spring application context is instantiated.
>
> CommandLineRunner beans can be defined within the same application context and can be ordered using the @Ordered interface or @Order
>   annotation.

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunnerSample implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger LOG =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommandLineAppStartupRunnerSample .class);

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Run method is executed");
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

Answer referred from site : https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring